# Possible to convert intraclass correlation coefficients ($ICC$) for use in meta-analysis of $r$?

Tags: meta-analysis, intraclass-correlation

I am trying to meta-analyze the validity evidence for a variety of new-fangled measurement devices. My effect size of interest is the correlation (Pearson's $r$) between measurements from these new devices, and those from the current gold-standard device. Some articles report Pearson's $r$ (or provide descriptive/inferential statistics that I can use to calculate $r$), but for certain variables, others provide the $ICC$ instead.

The rationale for reporting the $ICC$ (I think) is that although measurements are being taken from two different devices (i.e., *inter-*device measurement), they are being recorded simultaneously from the same subject and for the same variable of interest, and so there is *intra-*person dependency.

Two questions:
1) Is it possible to shoe-horn information from the $ICC$ into a form that can be combined in the meta-analysis where the effect size of interest is $r$?

2) OR, if I found enough articles that reported the $ICC$, is there a way of using this effect size in a meta-analysis?

Thank you!